# Oracle Materialized view takes hours to refresh

Tags: view, oracle11g, refresh, snapshot, materialized

I checked other related threads and cannot find an answer.

I have a materialized view which takes hours to refresha and the data is about 12 million. The mview is being refreshed as complete and non atomic. There are multiple indexes which I think making the refresh slow. Can someone suggest a solution?

This question pertains to oracle 11g and the mview is local copy of data located remotely. It contains no joins. Nologging is enabled while creating the mview.

Comment: heh missing quite a few things like used platform, rendering  techniques, data organization, and more without at least these no one could possibly help you out (because no one knows your project). also you should actually measure what part of your code is the bottleneck ... please edit your question and add neccessary details

Comment: Apologies. Edited my question. Not quite sure how I can find out the bottleneck. Hoping to get some suggestions on that.

Comment: I see now this is database question which is not my field at all... have slightly edit your question a little for more clarity (at first look I was thinking about rendering...) so hopefully some DB people here will see it and help ....(title and tags are very important for question search ... if you chose it right then the right people will see it)

Comment: still no responses? Databases are not thing of my but try to find some logging/monitoring tool for Oracle so you can see what is happening during the mview ... I expect in oracle bin or root directory are some ... or may be some command or command-line switch will turn debug features on. Also if you have more server/clients hooked by LAN, monitor the network also. try to assume how much data is transferring (MB,GB?) on what transfere speeds ...